# Microsoft graph subscription hooks for calendar events is getting triggered insanely multiple times

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

The subscription created for listening event updates in calendar is getting triggered multiple times.
even though there is only one subscription registered for url.

The api used for subscription is ***POST*** https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions

with body payload as below :-

```
{
   "changeType": "updated",
   "notificationUrl": "https://*******.ngrok.io/v1/microsoft/notify_me",
   "resource": "me/events",
   "expirationDateTime":"2020-05-30T22:23:45.9356913Z",
   "clientState": "secretClientValue",
   "latestSupportedTlsVersion": "v1_2"
}
```

After successful registration the hooks are getting called insanely multiple times,
I must make sure it gets called once as i've to perform critical db operations.

What am i doing wrong? why the hook is getting called multiple times ?

I also tried the delta function but it didn't worked and throws following error.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Unsupported request: Change tracking is not supported against 'microsoft.graph.event'.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "bb74dcd2-2890-41f6-a88c-2cc4b2e06078",
            "date": "2020-06-01T06:36:14"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any resolution for this? Also happening for me for a single user subscription

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that during your development flow you created multiple subscriptions to the same resource? (starting and stopping debug for example).

Regardless, there's no guarantee that change notifications will be delivered only once for a specific change, the subscriber should always deduplicate received notifications using the notification id, the resource id or a combination both.

Lastly, delta is supported for events but it [requires providing a start and end date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Comment: yes i've created multiple but i did deleted all of em' and kept only one,
And delta functions are not supported for events even though ive used start and end date

Comment: delta is supported on events so long as you query under the calendar view and not the /events endpoint (see the documentation link provided in my answer)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. When a person created an event, I received multiple times the JSON notification. I fixed that by returning a 202 response.

Now when a person creates an event, I only receive the notification one time.